# How to attribute Bootstrap dropdown to ajax inserted object

Tags: ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I'm doing a Django project and i need to insert rows dynamically (ajax) with a dropdown menu for each one. 
When the content is static it works just fine, but when new data are loaded from ajax, i can't bind it to the dropdown functionality and have a message like :

```
applyStyle.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
    at Object.onLoad (applyStyle.js:66)
    at index.js:69
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new t (index.js:67)
    at c.t.toggle (dropdown.js:177)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:328)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.c._jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (dropdown.js:315)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:472)
```

When i try to call the dropdown() function to bind it manually, i got the message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $dropdown1.dropdown is not a function
```

Is somebody knows what to do ?
Thank you !

Byga

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/CroudTech/vue-semantic/issues/1) ?

Comment: I can't try it now but i will and tell you if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Sure.. If you're using don't forget [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Yes, it was a problem of order to import the different elements like jquery/popper/bootstrap. Thank you !

Comment: Great. Can u post the same as answer or I can do it for you.?.  To make the future readers helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the order of import of the librarys like jquery/popper/bootstrap.

Thanks to Sulthan Allaudeen!